# At what time did the scourging at the pillar take place on Good Friday?

Tags: history, passion-of-jesus, good-friday

I have read some of the post on the accounts that took place between the time of the last supper through the crucifixion hour including the trials.
what time would the scourging at the pillar taken place?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  This is how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809

Answer (score 2):

The scourging of Jesus happened immediately after Barabbas had been released, so it would have been about **7 or 8 am on Friday morning**.

When harmonizing between the book of John, and the synoptic gospels, it is necessary to bare in mind that John used 'Roman time' and the others used 'Jewish time.'  So, the following references show "the 6th hour" (roman) as 6am, and "the 3rd hour" (jewish) as 9 am.

**FRI 6 am: Pilate’s decision:**

> It was about *the sixth hour*. He said to the Jews, "Behold your
>   King!" They cried out, "Away with him, away with him, crucify him!"
>   Pilate said to them, "Shall I crucify your King?" The chief priests
>   answered, "We have no king but Caesar." So he delivered him over to
>   them to be crucified. (John 19:13-16)

**FRI 7:30 am (approx): Jesus scourged:**

> So Pilate, wishing to satisfy the crowd, released for them Barabbas,
>   and *having scourged Jesus,* he delivered him to be crucified. (Mark
>   15:15)

**FRI 9 am: Jesus crucified:**

> And it was the *third hour* when they crucified him. (Mk 15:25)

Answer (score 0):

**At what time did the scourging at the pillar take place on Good Friday?**

The events of last twenty-four hours of our Savior’s life can be a bit confusing to fit into a chronology. No single gospel relates all that happened, and (what is more difficult) some of the gospels seem to contain points of contradiction.

> **Holy Thursday**
>
> **Mid-day:** Jesus’ disciples prepare the upper room for the Passover meal.
>
> **About 6pm:** Our Savior begins the Passover meal with his disciples.
>   After the institution of the Eucharist and the reception of communion by all twelve of the Apostles (and our Lord himself), Judas receives the dipped morsel (which was not the Eucharist, but simple bread) and departs.
>
> **About 8pm:** Jesus goes forth to the Garden of Gethsemane.
>
> **About 9pm:** Judas leads the soldiers to Jesus and the other apostles. Our Lord is arrested.
>   All flee, excepting Sts. Peter and John.
>
> **From 9pm till midnight:** Jesus is brought first to Annas and then to Caiaphas. These are the first two trials which our Lord undergoes. The trial before Caiaphas is often called the “Night Trial before the Sanhedrin”.
>   During the trial at the house of Annas, St. Peter denies Jesus the first time.
>   During the trial before Caiaphas, St. Peter denies the Lord twice more. The cock crows, and Peter flees weeping.
>   It is here that the Temple guards blindfold our Lord and strike him, asking him to prophecy for them.
>   Our Lord spends the evening in the dungeon of Caiaphas’ house.
>
> **Good Friday**
>
> **6am:** The Lord is brought to a brief trial before the Sanhedrin. They send him directly to Pilate.
>   Immediately after Jesus is sent forth from the Sanhedrin to Pilate, Judas returns to the chief priests, regretting his betrayal. Returning the money, Judas departs and hangs himself (probably before noon).
>
> **From 6am to 9am:** The fourth trial now, which is before Pilate, is very brief. The Lord is sent to Herod (the fifth trial) and then back to Pilate. The second time before Pilate is the occasion of the more extensive questioning of Jesus by Pilate, including the infamous question: What is truth? (John 18:38)
>   The fifth trial (which is before Pilate) is when the Jews choose Barabbas over Jesus.
>
> **About 10am:** The crowds ask for Jesus to be crucified.
>   **Jesus is scourged, crowned with thorns, cloaked in purple, and mocked.**
>   Then, taking up the Cross, our Savior begins the journey to Golgotha.
>
> **A little before noon:** Jesus reaches Golgotha, the place of the skull.
>   Then, he is stripped and nailed to the Cross.
>
> **From noon until 3pm:** Our Lord hangs, crucified upon the blessed Cross. Darkness covers the land.
>
> **3pm:** Jesus dies. The veil of the Temple is split in two. The earth shakes.
>
> **A little before 5pm:** St. Joseph of Arimathea courageously goes to Pilate and requests the body of Jesus. To prove that our Lord has expired, the centurion thrusts a lance through Christ’s side – blood and water pour forth.
>   Jesus’ body is prepared for burial by Nicodemus, the women, and his Mother.
>
> [A chronology of the passion and death of Jesus](http://newtheologicalmovement.blogspot.com/2012/04/chronology-of-passion-and-death-of.html)

Other Sources:

- [Follow the events of Jesus’ Passion with this timeline](https://aleteia.org/2018/03/28/follow-the-events-of-jesus-passion-with-this-timeline/)
- [Holy Week Timeline: Palm Sunday to Easter Sunday](https://www.aquinasandmore.com/blog/holy-week-timeline/)